# \twocolumnfalse create a new page

Tags: cross-referencing, memoir, two-column

When using \twocolumnfalse, the text of the new section begins on a new page, and I need to start on the same.
MWE:

```
 \documentclass[twocolumn]{memoir}
 \usepackage{blindtext}
 \usepackage{polyglossia}[2014/05/21]           
 \setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{russian}  
 \setotherlanguage{english}                       
 \setmonofont{Courier New}
 \newfontfamily\cyrillicfonttt{Courier New}
 \ifXeTeX
 \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Mapping=tex-text}
 \else

 \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
 \fi
 \setmainfont{Times New Roman}
 \newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Times New Roman}
 \setsansfont{Arial}
 \newfontfamily\cyrillicfontsf{Arial}  


 \begin{document}
 \blindtext
 \twocolumn[
 \begin{@twocolumnfalse}
    \begin{center}
        {REFERENCES}
    \end{center}
    
    \label{references}
\end{@twocolumnfalse}
]

\end{document}
```

it should be:
[image]

what is now:
[image]

Comment: Did you try loading the `cuted` package (from the `sttools` bundle) and use its `strip` environment.

Comment: Use the `multicols` package instead of `twocolumn` ?

Comment: Thanks you Peter Wilson! everything worked out

Comment: Sorry, hurried, I need to do exactly with \twocolumnfalse.

Comment: I created a new question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/570186/twocolumnfalse-creates-a-new-page