# \twocolumnfalse creates a new page

Tags: memoir, two-column

When using \twocolumnfalse, the text of the new section begins on a new page, and I need to start on the same.
In my case, you just need to save this method with \twocolumnfalse, but do it somehow differently
MWE:

```
 \documentclass[twocolumn]{memoir}
 \usepackage{blindtext}
 \usepackage{polyglossia}[2014/05/21]           
 \setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{russian}  
 \setotherlanguage{english}                       
 \setmonofont{Courier New}
 \newfontfamily\cyrillicfonttt{Courier New}
 \ifXeTeX
 \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Mapping=tex-text}
 \else

 \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
 \fi
 \setmainfont{Times New Roman}
 \newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Times New Roman}
 \setsansfont{Arial}
 \newfontfamily\cyrillicfontsf{Arial}  


 \begin{document}
 \blindtext
 \twocolumn[
 \begin{@twocolumnfalse}
    \begin{center}
        {REFERENCES}
    \end{center}
    
    \label{references}
\end{@twocolumnfalse}
]

\end{document}
```

it should be:
[image]

what is now:
[image]

p.s. I need to use exactly the \twocolumnfalse method
I could not use the strip environment and the multicol package

Answer (score 3):

It is very simple with the `strip` environment, form the `cuted` package:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{memoir}
 \usepackage{blindtext}
 \usepackage{polyglossia}[2014/05/21]
 \setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{russian}
 \setotherlanguage{english}
 \setmonofont{Courier New}
 \newfontfamily\cyrillicfonttt{Courier New}
 \ifXeTeX
 \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Mapping=tex-text}
 \else

 \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
 \fi
 \setmainfont{Times New Roman}
 \newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Times New Roman}
 \setsansfont{Arial}
 \newfontfamily\cyrillicfontsf{Arial}
\usepackage{cuted}

 \begin{document}
 \blindtext
 \begin{strip}
    \begin{center}
        {REFERENCES}
    \end{center}
\Blindtext[6]
    \label{references}
\end{strip}
\Blindtext[2}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: in my project I need to use exactly the \twocolumnfalse method

Comment: In this case, I don't know how to do it. You cannot challenge the dogma?